# Admin Page [no styles / buttons not working] opencart 2.0.1.1

Tags: administration, opencart2.x

I have a problem when loggin in to **administration page** on **opencart 2.0.1.1**

The admin page is not loading styles / images / buttons and is not accessible

why it apears like that for me ? i've tried different browsers but it's all the same

Comment: please check if you enable SSL URL's or do you have https:// in your admin URL instead of http:// ?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem when I used godaddy Plesk control panel. If your system is IIS 7+ or if you use plsek control panel, you must specify .less type in web.config file. For solution;

create web.config file in your main directory and write these codes;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
<mimeMap fileExtension=".less" mimeType="text/less" />
</staticContent>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

it solves the problem
for any quesiton : [my blog](http://dustsite.blogspot.com)

Comment: What if my server is Linux?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Opencart 2.0.1.1 admin panel won't display correctly](http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=190&t=137039#p537171)